# Server offer with "2-sockets and 1 virtual guest", what does this mean?

Tags: virtualization, linux, socket

I've read in a server support website that they offer a "2-sockets with 1 virtual guest" packet for a Linux Server.. but what does the "2-sockets" part mean? I know servers may be virtualized but I'm uncertain about the whole phrase

Can someone explain me simply please?

Comment: Can you point us to the website so we can see it in context?

Comment: @Matt: Looks like this site https://www.redhat.com/apps/store/server/

Answer (score 3):

This is a Redhat Subscription slang.

It means that you have to buy your subscription based on the given hardware and the purpose of your Redhat system.

Your server's mainboard has space for one or more CPU sockets. Based on that number you have to buy the subscription with the appropriate "Sockets".

The virtual guests describe how many virtual machines you are going to install on the hardware. The bought number is the upper limit you are allowed to install.

For more information you probably should contact the Redhat sales office.